# Read Only Text Column With Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I made a very easy one HTML input column. I added JavaScript to it with a checkbox in it.
When I clicked check box checked I want write the text or unchecked the text box read only how to solve my problem. Give for example for my code

```
<input type="text" id="inputID" value="abc"></input>

    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" checked>

    <script>
   document.getElementById('inputID').readOnly = true;

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event listener to the [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event on the checkbox.

```
<input type="text" id="inputID" value="abc" readonly></input>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" >
<script>
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('myCheck');
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
        document.getElementById('inputID').readOnly = !this.checked; 
    });
</script>
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sygn/9d6n3o7e/14/)

Comment: working.. but first time i want check box unchecked so read only. when i checked the check box  i want write the text

Comment: Change the initial attributes on the the HTML and invert the change logic. I've updated the answer